# python ValueError: column index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am running one simple python program with my files. This program works fine on one of my machines with the file, `fileA.bed`. But this program doesn't work in another machine with the same file. I installed same python version, 2.7.6, same required modules, scipy ('0.15.1'), numpy('1.8.2'), iced ('0.2.2-git') (same versions in both machines). The error message is something about `ValueError: column index exceeds matrix dimensions` (please see below). Could you please help, what could cause this problem?

```
python Dense.py -b fileA.bed 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Dense.py", line 34, in <module>
    counts = io.load_counts(args.filename, lengths=lengths)
  File "$PATH/Python-2.7.6/venv_iced_2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/iced/io/_io_else.py", line 30, in load_counts
    counts = sparse.coo_matrix((X[:, 2], (X[:, 0], X[:, 1])), shape=shape)
  File "$PATH/Python-2.7.6/venv_iced_2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 206, in __init__
    self._check()
  File "$PATH/Python-2.7.6/venv_iced_2.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 262, in _check
    raise ValueError('column index exceeds matrix dimensions')
ValueError: column index exceeds matrix dimensions
```

Answer (score 3):

I can reproduce this error by creating a `sparse.coo_matrix` with:

```
In [1075]: sparse.coo_matrix(([1,1,1],([0,1,1],[0,1,3])), shape=(2,3))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1075-40a6338a3244> in <module>()
----> 1 sparse.coo_matrix(([1,1,1],([0,1,1],[0,1,3])), shape=(2,3))

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py in __init__(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
    180             self.data = self.data.astype(dtype)
    181 
--> 182         self._check()
    183 
    184     def getnnz(self, axis=None):

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py in _check(self)
    236                 raise ValueError('row index exceeds matrix dimensions')
    237             if self.col.max() >= self.shape[1]:
--> 238                 raise ValueError('column index exceeds matrix dimensions')
    239             if self.row.min() < 0:
    240                 raise ValueError('negative row index found')

ValueError: column index exceeds matrix dimensions
```

I'm telling it that the matrix should be 2x3, but one of the column values is 3, where as it should be in the [0,3) range (less than 3).

I know nothing about your `iced` package, or the data in the file that it apparently is trying to load.  But hopefully this gives you an idea of where to search for the problem.